# Unable to get column index with table.getColumn method using custom table Model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, abstracttablemodel

I have created a custom TableModel using AbstractTableModel. I am able to populate my JTable. But my JTable has a button column say "Button1". So I am using CellRenderer method to add buttons to column and CellEditor to add actions, but I am getting exception at LINE:3.

```
CustomModelForTable customTableModel = new CustomModelForTable(colNames, data);
tableA = new JTable(customTableModel);

**LINE:3** 
tableA.getColumn("Button1").setCellRenderer(new JButtonRendererClass());
tableA.getColumn("Button1").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumnIndex(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:265)
```

I am getting this error because I am not able to get the Column from my custom Table. But can some one help me out with this issue.

I am using the following [**source**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) to perform this task. In this source they are using DefaultTableModel where as in my case I am using `AbstractTableModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retrieve columns by identifier, you have to set one using [TableColumn.setIdentifier()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setIdentifier%28java.lang.Object%29).

EDIT:

Note that according to specs of `TableColumn.getIdentifier()`:

> If the identifier is null, getIdentifier() returns getHeaderValue as a
>   default.

That is how it works in the linked example.

EDIT:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TableDemo extends JPanel {
    public TableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        add(scrollPane);

        table.getColumn("Column1").setCellRenderer(new TestCellRenderer());
        table.getColumn("Column2").setCellRenderer(new TestCellRenderer());
    }

    class TestCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{ }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = { "Column1", "Column2" };
        private Object[][] data = { { "1", "1" }, { "2", "2" } };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TableDemo newContentPane = new TableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Che What is the header value for that column? See my last edit.

Comment: Column header value is Button1 which is of type JButton class

Comment: @Che Make sure you implement getColumnName() in your model. See my last edit for a simple example of a model.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a champ. Thank you. But just one explanation regarding this. How getColumnName(int col) method helped to achieve this?

Comment: @Che When new column is created in `JTable`, column's name is used to set column's header name (unless this column already has a header value). Then during lookup by identifier, the column's header name is used in case its identifier is null (part of `getIdentifier()` method).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16578/discussion-between-che-and-max)

Comment: @Che ditto, it turned to be an challenging question.

Answer (score 3):

1.use [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) by @camickr

2.`JButton` in `JTable` represents `String value` stored in `XxxTableModel`, then have to override the `ColumnClass`

```
     public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return Date.class;
            case 1:
                return Integer.class;
            case 2:
                return Long.class;
            case 3:
                return Double.class;
            case 4:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 5:
                return Icon.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }
```

Cells in the Column should be editable

```
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                return false;
            case 1:
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
```

3.everything is about your `AbstractTableModel`, maybe there no reason use that, use `DefaultTableModel` before, in the case that you understand  `How XxxTableModel works`, then you can to override methods for `JTable` with `AbstractTableModel`